# How can I optimize my zip function in c# to be faster?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, foreach, webdriver

How can I optimize "findelements" and "tolist" portions of my code to run faster? I am making a list of field headers and a list of its values by cssselectors, zipping them, and throwing them into my database. This is the slowest part of my program and I was wondering how I can make this process speed up. Please help thank you <3

```
    public static void zipper()
    {
        //Database connection
        MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(mongoinfo);
        var db = dbClient.GetDatabase("TestDB");
        var collec = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("TestDB");

        //Zip editList
        foreach (var item in editList)
        {

            //Console.WriteLine(newURL);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(item);

            IList<String> keys = new List<string>();
            IList<IWebElement> keyList = 
            driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td.Field.box"))
            .ToList();
            foreach (IWebElement key in keyList)
            {
                if (key.Text != " Person authorizing adjustment")
                {
                    keys.Add(key.Text.TrimStart(' '));
                }
            }
            IList<String> vals = new List<string>();
            IList<IWebElement> valList = 
            driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td.Data.box"))
            .ToList();
            foreach (IWebElement val in valList)
            {
                vals.Add(val.Text);
            }

            int keynum = keys.Count();
            Console.WriteLine(keynum);
            int valnum = vals.Count();
            Console.WriteLine(valnum);
            var keysAndVals = keys.Zip(vals, (first,second) => 
            first+":"+second);
            IList<String> kv = keysAndVals.ToList();
            BsonArray bArray = new BsonArray();
            foreach (var term in kv)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(term);
                bArray.Add(term);
            }
            var document = new BsonDocument();

            document.Add("TestDB", bArray);
            collec.InsertOneAsync(document);
        }
    }
```

Are there implicit waits I can use? 
or am I missing async/await that needs to be used somewhere?

Comment: `.FindElements` already returns an `IEnumerable`, so you really don't need the `.ToList` there.

Comment: How slow is it now? How fast are you aiming for?

Comment: This is really a question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @itsme86 I agree.